# How to find the adjacent cell value in excel using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel-2010

I am stuck with this sitaution. I read the forum and have tried numerous methods to solve this but nothings working.

Here is the scenario:

I am autogenerating an excel worksheet using vb.net. This worksheet gets populated with 200 data values in column A and 200 different data values in column B. I then find the maximum value of column B with its associated address (e.g. maxvalue = 2.59, address $B$89 ). I now need to find the value of the adjacent cell (in column A) and display that value in a message box.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Sudhir

Comment: Can we see the code you tried but did not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim xlsWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim xlsWB As Excel.Workbook = Nothing

    Try

        xlsApp = New Excel.Application
        xlsApp.Visible = True
        xlsWorkBooks = xlsApp.Workbooks
        xlsWB = xlsWorkbooks.Open("c:\my_excel_file.xls")

        xlsWB.Range("B89").Select   'This will move the cursor to B89 cell
        Dim myValue as String = ""

        myValue = xlsWB.Activecell.Offset(0,-1).Value
                      'Offset(0,-1) means we are interested in the
                      'cell in which lies on the same row (0 for y axis)
                      'and to the left of the current one, by one cell
                      'which means -1 . If we want the cell in column D92 then 
                      'we would use Offset(3,2) 


    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

        xlsWB.Close()
        xlsWB = Nothing
        xlsApp.Quit()
        xlsApp = Nothing

    End Try
```